# Mysql limit insert/update/delete to being called from trigger (Not from application code)

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, innodb

My use case is that I have a MYSQL table which has a change tracking table behind it.  Both tables are InnoDB.
I'd like to use triggers to enforce two things.

**One**: forcing a copy to be made of previous state on every update (update trigger performs insert select query)   This is non-trivial and I have already done it.

**Two**: limit access to the second table to read only for users, while triggers can still insert/update/delete as necessary

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've written the triggers.  I have no IDEA where to begin with the permissions.  The trigger I have does an insert select (selecting the current data in the table row and copying it to the history table) then allows the update or insert to proceed.  Currently I haven't figured out anything regarding user management

Comment: How do the users access the second table?

Comment: Users should be read only on the second table.  It should only be AFFECTED (Insert/Update/Delete) by the trigger.  That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do, restrict Insert/Update/Delete to the trigger

Comment: But what program are your users using to access the table? A webpage or phpmyadmin for instance?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question.  This is part of a larger application which uses php to serve the data to a javascript/ajax based ui.  The actual access is handled by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research on user access and triggers has dug up this:

[Mysql 5.5 reference manual: 19.6 Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-security.html)

Turns out that stored programs can be assigned a user to run as.  Triggers are stored programs.  By restricting Insert, Update, and Delete to a special user which only will be used by a trigger and using the DEFINER attribute of the trigger (or any stored program) I can make the trigger which I want to have access run under that user.